# Using imdbpy2sql.py to populate PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, imdbpy

I'm trying to use imdbpy2sql.py documented at http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/docs/README.sqldb.txt but I am having trouble with syntax & directories. To simplify things I loaded the IMDb files in a subdirectory of "C:\Users\dom\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts" eg: "C:\Users\dom\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts\imdb"

Then I executed: 
    os.chdir("C:\Users\dom\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts")

I tried to use a PostgreSQL database with variations of the following command and got:

> > > imdbpy2sql.py -d /imdb -u 'postgres://sid:asdf@host/imdb'

File "", line 1
    imdbpy2sql.py -d /imdb -u 'postgres://sid:asdf@host/imdb'
                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

In a last grasp effort I tried M$ SQL server and had a similar error:

```
>>> imdbpy2sql.py -d /imdb -u mssql://dom:@localhost/imdb
```

File "", line 1
    imdbpy2sql.py -d /imdb -u mssql://dom:@localhost/imdb
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tips on syntax would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
imdbpy2sql.py -d /imdb -u 'postgres://sid:asdf@host/imdb'
```

is a *command prompt* command invocation, not Python code. You cannot run it from a Python command prompt.

You would need to open `cmd.exe` (on Windows) and run something along the lines of:

```
c:
cd \Users\dom\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts
python imdbpy2sql.py -d /imdb -u 'postgres://sid:asdf@host/imdb'
```

If you wanted to fire it off from within a Python interpreter you could do so by using `subprocess.check_call` or `os.system`.

Additionally, the leading slash on `/imdb` will cause Python to think you mean `\imdb`, ie "the directory named `imdb` in the root of this drive, so it'll complain it can't find `c:\imdb`. You probably want to just say `imdb` without the slash.

Comment: Thanks so much! Now it's just complaining about SQLobject but activepython says it's already installed:

Comment: @trianIMDB Couldn't tell you much about that bit, especially with the detail provided. Post a new question if you're still stuck after searching for a while and thinking about it.